# Convert array of objects to single objects while keeping keys in same order

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to convert `Objects` in an `Array` to one single `Object` in javascript. Here are objects in an array and logic to convert it to one single object.

```js
var arrObj=[{"Plain bold italic text": "2"},{29: "1"},{24: "2"},{21: "2"},{26: "2"},{27: "2"}];
     var obj={};
     arrObj.forEach((element, index) => {
          obj[Object.keys(element)[0]] = parseInt(Object.values(element).toString());
      });
      console.log(obj);
```

Somehow it is my requirement to keep `string` as well as `numbers` as keys, but I want to maintain the same order for keys. My logic sorts keys which I don't desire. 
 Expected output:
 `{"Plain bold italic text": 2,  "29": 1,"24": 2,"21": 2,"26": 2,"27": 2}`

Comment: it does not work for keys like numbers, because this keys are sorted (first).

Comment: @NinaScholz 29 , 24,21,26 , 27 are not sorted. But operations makes it so. I want to have same order of keys as it apears in array .

Comment: Object order can't be guaranteed in Javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [object property order between integer indexes, symbols and strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45827457/object-property-order-between-integer-indexes-symbols-and-strings)

Answer (score 0):

No, It is not possible to maintain same order with `Object` You can maintain order only with `Array` by shifting value with `sort` and other functions but you can not same with  `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

You can Hack the object key order with [Map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
var myObject = new Map();
var arrObj=[{"Plain bold italic text": "2"},{29: "1"},{24: "2"},{21: "2"},{26: "2"},{27: "2"}];
var result = arrObj.reduce(function(accumulator, object){
     
      for(var key in object){
       myObject.set(key, object[key]);
       return myObject
     }
},{})

for (var [key, value] of result) {
  console.log(key + ' = ' + value);
}
```

**READ MORE:** http://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/map-to-the-rescue-adding-order-to-object-properties/

Answer (score -1):

This isn't doing exactly what you want, but it's the only way I know of to keep everything in the same order - by prepending an underscore, it causes all of the keys to behave like strings and stay in the right order. I can't imagine what your use case is, but this would potentially give you a workaround.

```js
var arrObj=[{"Plain bold italic text": "2"},{29: "1"},{24: "2"},{21: "2"},{26: "2"},{27: "2"}];
     var obj={};
     arrObj.forEach((element, index) => {
          obj["_" + Object.keys(element)[0]] = parseInt(Object.values(element).toString());
      });
      console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Note that by spec, `Object.keys` does not guarantee order. It's only that most implementations give you the same order as e.g. `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`.

Comment: Oh I know, this is by no means a good idea, just the one way of mimicking what OP is attempting to do

Answer (score -2):

the problem that you have is that the properties order in objects is not guaranteed in JavaScript; you need to use an `Array` in order to preserve it (as you have in your `objArray`.

Definition of an Object from ECMAScript:

> #### Object
>
> An object is a member of the
>   type Object. **It is an unordered collection of properties** each of which
>   contains a primitive value, object, or
>   function. A function stored in a
>   property of an object is called a
>   method.

another solution would be a map instead of a plain object as this article says:
[enter link description here](http://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/map-to-the-rescue-adding-order-to-object-properties/)

here you have a working example with map:

```js
var arrObj = [{
  "Plain bold italic text": "2"
}, {
  29: "1"
}, {
  24: "2"
}, {
  21: "2"
}, {
  26: "2"
}, {
  27: "2"
}];
var obj = new Map();

arrObj.forEach((element, index) => {
  obj.set(Object.keys(element)[0], parseInt(Object.values(element).toString()));
});
for (var [key, value] of obj) {
  console.log(key, value);
}
```

Comment: Copy paste answer is not a good thing https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/6236938.

Comment: @NishantDixit you are incorrect, I added a proper solution and a link to where I got the code to make the users code work.

Comment: The issue with your copy answer is that the spec where that definition comes from is very very old. You probably copied that from [the question that pops up first on google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order) that is from 2011.

Comment: @ASDFGerte but it behaves the same at the moment, it didn't change, so actually it doesnt matter if the definition is new or old as the universe.
I added the definition and a solution using another structure (`Map`). dont know what is the problem with that :(

Comment: It did change considerably in ES6. You can even see in the comments of the answer you copied from that people are stating things like "This answer is false in ES2015". Here is the afaik currently apropriate [question/answer pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties).

Comment: As a fun fact - if you post anything about object property order on stackoverflow you are almost guaranteed to get half a dozen wrong or outdated answers/comments. The topic is just very confusing and also changed over time. Also using object properties' order is not what one should do, therefore treating them as unordered is usually the best practice anyways.